# How can I transfer text from one textbox to another textbox without it looping and not sending the text?

Tags: c#

I have searched for what I am asking of you but I may have been wording it wrong, so I hope what I have typed is easy to understand.

I am creating a Css formatter with two textboxes using `WinForms`

I would like it to take a css long format code in the first `textBoxLongFormat` then appear in the second, `textboxShortFormat`, as css short code.

I have a bit of code for both text boxes and a separate class of other code for the behind the scenes to change the format.

The class works but I’m having a problem with `textBoxLongFormat` and I’m guessing it will happen the other way round, the code is looping on its self and not closing, so it’s not sending the format to `textBoxShortFormat` so nothing happens.

There is something I am doing wrong, I know, but I cannot see it. What is it that I am doing wrong? It will be great to have your help.

Here is the code for the textboxes if it helps.

What is it that i need to add or to make it work?

```
    private void textBoxLongFormat_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CssFormatConverter cssLongFormatConverter = new CssFormatConverter();
        string longFormatCss = textBoxLongFormat.Text;
        string shortFormatCss = cssLongFormatConverter.ToShortFormat(longFormatCss);
        textBoxShortFormat.Text = shortFormatCss;
    }

    private void textBoxShortFormat_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CssFormatConverter cssShortFormatConverter = new CssFormatConverter();
        string shortFormatCss = textBoxShortFormat.Text;
        string longFormatCss = cssShortFormatConverter.ToLongFormat(shortFormatCss);
        textBoxLongFormat.Text = longFormatCss;
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would recommend you to use a timer, grab a "copy" in memory of the actual state of the textbox1, work with that copy, and send it to the textbox2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a boolean check that indicates the other textbox is updating.

```
bool isUpdating = false;
private void textBoxLongFormat_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isUpdating)
    {
        isUpdating = true;
        CssFormatConverter cssLongFormatConverter = new CssFormatConverter();
        string longFormatCss = textBoxLongFormat.Text;
        string shortFormatCss = cssLongFormatConverter.ToShortFormat(longFormatCss);
        textBoxShortFormat.Text = shortFormatCss;
        isUpdating = false;
    }
}

private void textBoxShortFormat_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isUpdating)
    {
        isUpdating = true;
        CssFormatConverter cssShortFormatConverter = new CssFormatConverter();
        string shortFormatCss = textBoxShortFormat.Text;
        string longFormatCss = cssShortFormatConverter.ToLongFormat(shortFormatCss);
        textBoxLongFormat.Text = longFormatCss;
        isUpdating = false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'd agree with this, depending on what the class is doing, you'll need to `return` something (probably a `boolean`), letting the loops know it has been completed.

Comment: Thank you John koerner it works great. it has been bugging me, i hope i can soon get to grips of c# soon, thank you again

Comment: @plast1K I believe the intention is to keep both textboxes in sync, making the loops an unintended sideeffect. Thus no return value is required.

Answer (score 0):

Before updating a TextBox, unsubscribe it from the `TextChanged` event. Then update. Then re-subscribe.

In the first one, that would be:

```
textBoxShortFormat.TextChanged -= textBoxShortFormat_TextChanged;
textBoxShortFormat.Text = shortFormatCss;
textBoxShortFormat.TextChanged += textBoxShortFormat_TextChanged;
```